# "let alone" after an affirmative sentence

Tags: grammaticality

I'd like to know if the following sentences are natural to native ears.

1. It takes too much time, **let alone** money.
2. In Scotland we can have a range of weather conditions in one hour, **let alone** one day.

I'd appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

[Oxford Living Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/let_alone) defines "let alone" as "*Used to indicate that something is far less likely or suitable than something else already mentioned*".

Most of the examples they give are negative, but not quite all.

> It takes too much time, let alone money.

This could be paraphrased as: "It takes too much time, and (it takes) even more money."

The suggestion is that money is a bigger barrier than time, but time is too big a hurdle to overcome before you even think about the issue of money.

The meaning is somewhat negative here: the person is saying that a particular project or idea won't be able to go ahead.

> In Scotland we can have a range of weather conditions in one hour, let alone one day.

This could be paraphrased as: "In Scotland we [often] have a [wide] range of weather conditions in [just] one hour, and (we have) even more (weather conditions) in one day."

Even just the hour on its own is a lot to think about, a lot to consider or account for or report on or deal with - and a day is twenty-four of those.

Comment: As a native speaker, do you find both sentences natural English?And while the first can be considered part of a negative context, the second is rather unclear; what is negative about it?

Comment: @Apollyon: "Weather conditions" has somewhat negative connotations. We don't (typically) use the word "conditions" in the context of  mild, balmy days with sun and a blue sky, but with high winds, or drought, or heavy rains, etc.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo Do you think the preceding context for the second sentence could be a discussion on the unfeasibility of camping in Scotland for a day? If so, that's something negative.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo  If negativity is a prerequisite for the use of "let alone," I suppose it's not natural to say, "John knows Classical Greek, Latin, German, Japanese, and French, let alone English," is it?

Comment: @Apollyon: The verb **knows** in the affirmative does not seem compatible with a **let alone** construction.  *John has no time to learn English, let alone dabble in Klingon.*

Comment: I think the sentences are natural.  I also think the context for the second sentence is likely to be negative in some way, e.g. discussing the difficulty of a particular course of action.  I'm not sure that negativity is a prerequisite: I think we could say "There are an unfathomably large number of atoms in the universe, let alone subatomic particles".  Mind you, perhaps even there there's a sense that I'm talking about how difficult it is to count them.  No, you couldn't say "John knows Classical Greek... [etc]... let alone English".

Comment: But *unfathomably* supplies the negative sense there.

Comment: If I replace "unfathomably" with "extremely", it still works, I think.

Comment: What if you replace the entire phrase with "many"?

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo I think rjpond's sense of "negativity" is different from lexical or grammatical negation. There is nothing grammatically negative about my first quoted example, which he still views as couched within a negative context.

Comment: @Apollyon: The complement of **let alone** is to be barred from consideration because that which was mentioned in the preceding statement  already reaches or surpasses a threshold of some kind. As rjpond mentions in the context of the weather, there is a limit to how many conditions we can "deal with".  Context can supply the limit, it need not be explicitly stated; but some word or phrase in the statement alludes to it.

Comment: *His erratic driving was already enough to establish "probable cause" to permit his car to be searched, let alone the fact that his passenger was bound and gagged.*

Comment: Change "is to be barred from consideration" to "can be barred from consideration".  We don't even need to "go there".

Comment: Is contextual negativity required for the "His erratic driving was already..." example? Maybe the context would be discussing how difficult it is to defend someone's innocence?

Comment: @Apollyon: The only requirement is that the there be two things, one of them the lesser (in some way or on some scale) in the given context. We need not concern ourselves with the greater thing because the lesser thing has has already met or exceeded a threshold. The lesser thing is already sufficient; we can disregard the greater thing.  "There are more things in *Glasgow Scotland* than are dreamed of in your philosophy, let alone in heaven and earth."